# Is there any way to pass the setter of a property to a delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates, properties

I know this question has already been asked, but this time I have two additional constraints:

1. Reflection cannot be used.
2. I don't want to pass a wrapper around a property's setter. I want to pass the setter itself:

   ```
   // NO! NO! NO!
   myObject.MyMethod(value => anotherObject.AnotherProperty = value);
   ```

Comment: Why can't you use reflection to obtain that setter? I would start with a lambda of the form `(o)=>o.Property` and use reflection to find the associated setter.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Why use Reflection to do at runtime what could be done at compile time? And also: Why complicate things inside an already complex generic?

Comment: @Eduardo why do you think this can be done at compile time?

Comment: If you can't use reflection, and you can't use a lambda expression, then you're SOL. This is otherwise impossible, as C# does not expose the setter as a method.

Comment: @Wesley Wiser: Because it should! Certainly, you can pass an ordinary method that has the same signature as the setter and behaves as the setter. Why shouldn't I be able to pass the setter itself, then?

Comment: @Eduardo, a commonly requested feature for C# is some sort of `memberof` functionality akin to `typeof` that could allow a compile-time reference to member information that can otherwise only be accessed via Reflection (such as properties, methods and property accessors.)  My understanding is that the C# team likes the idea, but there are boundary cases complicating its implementation and there are too many other desired features with a broader user base that have priority.  Lambda expressions do help, as now you can at least get compile-time checking, even if Reflection does the final work.

Comment: @Mike Caron: Certainly, the runtime supports treating the setter as a method. The `PropertyInfo` class has a `GetSetMethod` method.

Comment: @Eduardo, the CLR doesn't support properties at all. All it knows are methods and fields. However, the C# team has explicitly chosen to not make these special methods generally available. Why? Dunno. However, it is unlikely to change any time in the near future. Point is, you cannot access the setter though C# directly, you must use reflection.

Comment: @Eduardo That's certainly true. The issue with what your suggesting (at least from my point of view) is that it makes the code ambiguous. What does `Console.WriteLine(myObject.MyProperty.GetType())` print, the type of the value of MyProperty or `MethodInfo`? If it prints `MethodInfo` does the `MethodInfo` object refer to the property getter or setter?

Comment: It seems like I discovered lenses way before I discovered Haskell!

Comment: @SergiyByelozyorov: s***, outta luck (?)

Answer (score 11):

The answer to your question is going to be no.  At least as far as C# is concerned.

Why?  Let's say that you have the following object:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int SomeProp { get; set; }
}
```

you know that under the hood the compiler will autogenerate int get_SomeProp() and void set_SomeProp(int value) for you (plus the backing field), so you should be able to do this:

```
var someMethod = foo.get_SomeProp;
```

and you can - almost.  You get this error from the compiler: "cannot explicitly call operator or accessor".  So without reflection or a wrapper, you're SOL.  Maybe.  I say maybe because just because C# doesn't let you treat a getter or setter like a real method, it doesn't mean that some other .NET language can't.  For example, I can write this in F#:

```
namespace PassSetter

module mucker =
    let muckWithFoo (aFoo:Foo) =
        aFoo.set_SomeProp
```

and now muckWithFoo is a function declared as Foo->(int->unit), which is equivalent to a method that returns delegate void d(int value).  In essence, you can use another module to break the C# compiler constraint, if need be.  I picked F# only because I have the compiler handy, but I bet you could do this with C++/CLI as well.

The main difference between this and a wrapper is that even though you still need to write a wrapper for every type for which you would like to get a delegate from, that wrapper doesn't end up attached to the final delegate.

I don't know what your issue is with the "no reflection" constraint - is it that you're running in an environment that forbids reflection or that you believe that you're so performance bound that you can't afford to use reflection.  If it's the latter, then there are several more options open to you that give you much better performance than simply reflection to get the property set method and then invoke it (effectively call by name).

Comment: What I want to achieve is conceptual purity. Reflection makes programs more difficult to understand, and should be confined to when it is really needed for.

Comment: Conceptual purity is a laudable goal, but at some point you have to strike a balance between that and practicality.  Lambda wrappers are completely acceptable in readability and will probably be good in performance.  If it's not performant enough, there are more options, but they only get uglier.

Comment: As a for-instance, I can give you a function GetSetter(object o, Type t, string propname) that returns the set method of the property.  It would do effectively what the F# code does, but at runtime and on any type.  It's just that the code to do that isn't precisely pretty (and I would likely do it in IL).

Comment: @plith Putting a property name in a string literal is usually a bad idea. I prefer the Lamda-trick.

Answer (score 7):

Define this helper function(You'll need to add the error checking):

```
Action<TObject,TValue> GetSetter<TObject,TValue>(Expression<Func<TObject,TValue>> property)
{
    var memberExp=(MemberExpression)property.Body;
    var propInfo=(PropertyInfo)memberExp.Member;
    MethodInfo setter=propInfo.GetSetMethod();
    Delegate del=Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<TObject,TValue>),setter);
    return (Action<TObject,TValue>)del;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Action<MyClass,int> setter=GetSetter((MyClass o)=>o.IntProperty);
```

This is not exactly what you want(It uses reflection), but probably as close as you'll get. The returned delegate is the setter itself, no wrapper.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use an interface?

```
interface IPropertySetter {
  string Property { set; }
}
```

Have your class implement it:

```
class MyClass : IPropertySetter {
  public string Property { get; set; }
}
```

And pass it to your object:

```
var c = new MyClass();
myObject.MyMethod(c);

...

void MyMethod(IPropertySetter setter) {
  setter.Property = someValue;
  // you can also store the "setter" and use it later...
}
```

Comment: @Jordão: I want to pass the setters of wildly different properties from wildly different objects to that delegate.

Comment: OK, that's fair. Why do you think that using a lambda is bad? It's a compile time construct.

Comment: @Jordão: If C# supported function inlining the way C++ does, I wouldn't mind. But C# doesn't.

Comment: Function inlining is done at the CLR level. Why do you think performance will be a problem in this case?

Comment: @Jordão: Why should I wait until JIT time to do what could be done at build time?

Comment: Because you don't really want to second guess the compiler or runtime optimizations. It really doesn't pay off in most cases.

Comment: It's impossible for the C# compiler to do cross-assembly inlining.  So the JITter already needs to implement method inlining. So why should the C# compiler duplicate that functionality? Almost all code optimizations happen at JIT time. Why should the compiler be bothered with optimizations that the jitter can do for all languages?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Actually, I don't even want the optimization. I want the conceptual purity of not writing a wrapper that should not be needed.

Comment: @Eduardo: you're contradicting yourself: "If C# supported function inlining the way C++ does, I wouldn't mind [using lambdas]". What is it that you _really_ want?

Comment: @Jordão: Purity. Power. Efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

C# does not allow this (because of the specialname attribute the compiler generates on the set_AnotherProperty method), however J# would because it does not support the property syntax.

This is what the code *would* look like.

```
  Action<int> x = set_AnotherProperty(1);
```

However, the C# compiler tells you

```
Error   3   'Program.AnotherProperty.set': 
cannot explicitly call operator or accessor
```

Comment: More info from the [Compiler Error CS0571](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z47a7kdw(v=VS.100).aspx): _You should not use or explicitly call such method names_.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure the answer is no. The most common approach to this is to use lambda expressions, see for example the common solution to hard-coded INotifyPropertyChanged strings:

http://10rem.net/blog/2010/12/16/strategies-for-improving-inotifypropertychanged-in-wpf-and-silverlight

There are no other magic ways!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass a wrapper around a property's setter, you can go the other way around and let the setter be a wrapper around a method. For example:

```
public MyClass
{
    private Foo _myProperty;
    public Foo MyProperty
    {
        get { return _myProperty; }
        set { MyPropertySetter(value); }
    }

    public void MyPropertySetter(Foo foo)
    {
        _myProperty = foo;
    }
}
```

then do:

```
myObject.Mymethod(myOtherObject.MyPropertySetter);
```

It's not pretty, but it does what you want done.

Comment: It is not only not pretty. It is _by definition_ what I do not want to do.

Comment: @Eduardo León: Then you should be clearer in your question. This solution neither use Reflection nor pass a wrapper around a property's setter. Just as your question asked.

Comment: The standalone method _is_ a wrapper around the setter, whether it is anonymous or named.

Answer (score 0):

For your constraints, it seems you can't use properties at all. If the performance considerations are so strong that you can't simply wrap the setter in a lambda, then you might want to change your style of development. That's normally what's done in extreme cases of code tuning. Put on your Java hat and create explicit setter and getter methods *in your C# code*:

```
class MyClass {
  private string _value;
  public void setProperty(string value) { _value = value; } 
}
```

No properties involved... But, how much that *really* buys you over lambdas? I wouldn't think it's noticeable.

Comment: Java would be even worse than C#. Its so-called generics are broken, and the library I am writing relies heavily on generics.

Comment: I'm not telling you to use Java, but to use a Java idiom in C#. Sorry if I wasn't explicit enough. I rectified that.

Answer (score 0):

A property can be wrapped in a delegate, if intellectual purity and lexical beauty are not synonymous. Of course it is not quite a property, with null being a trigger for read/write operations and the need for the 'called' to treat it like a function, after all.

```
xType1 xProperty1 {get;set;}

xType2 xProperty1 {get;set;}

xCallingFunction()
{
   ....
   xCalledFunction( 
     ((s)=> s == null ? xProperty1 : (xProperty1 = s)),
     ((s)=> s == null ? xProperty2 : (xProperty2 = s))
     );
   ....
}

....

xCalledFunction( Func<xType, xType> parm1, Func<xType2, xType2> parm2 )
   var p1 = parm1(null);
   parm2( newValue );
   parm1( parm1(null) + 16 );
```